# как сделать анимацию движения таракана

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация, dom

Нужно было сделать анимацию ползающих жуков, я сделал как:

```js
function initialBugs(bugs) {
    var containerRect = document.getElementById("bug-container").getBoundingClientRect();

    for (let bug of bugs ) {
        var initialX = Math.random() < 0.6 ? - bug.offsetWidth : containerRect.width;
        var initialY = Math.floor(Math.random() * containerRect.height);
        bug.style.left = initialX + "px";
        bug.style.top = initialY + "px";
    }
}

function moveRoach() {
    var bugs = document.getElementsByClassName("bug-icon");
    var container = document.getElementById("bug-container");
    initialBugs(bugs);

    for (let bug of bugs) {
        var targetX = Math.floor(Math.random() * container.offsetWidth);
        var targetY = Math.floor(Math.random() * container.offsetHeight);


        var targetAngle = Math.atan2(targetY - parseInt(bug.style.top), targetX - parseInt(bug.style.left)) * (180 / Math.PI);
        var rotationAngle = targetAngle;
    

        bug.style.transform = "rotate(" + rotationAngle + "deg)";
        bug.style.left = targetX + "px";
        bug.style.top = targetY + "px";
    }
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    moveRoach();
    setInterval(moveRoach, 9000);
});
```

```css
#bug-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    
}
.bug-icon {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: left 5s linear, top 5s linear;
}
```

```html
<header class="header" id="bug-container">
    <img class="bug-icon" id="bug" src="https://svgshare.com/i/t12.svg">
    <img class="bug-icon" id="bug" src="https://svgshare.com/i/t12.svg">
    <img class="bug-icon" id="bug" src="https://svgshare.com/i/t12.svg">

</header>
```

Для каждого жука определяю случайные координаты x и y внутри **контейнера** с использованием `Math.random()`.

Далее вычисляю угол между текущим положением жука и новым `(x, y)`, сделал это с помощью функции `Math.atan2()`, которая возвращает арктангенс от отношения разности координат `y - parseInt(bug.style.top)` к разности координат `x - parseInt(bug.style.left)`, затем этот угол перевожу из радиан в градусы

Далее вычисляю угол поворота жука, вычитая из `targetAngle` фиксированный угол -45°(так как на иконке он так повёрнут), разница углов `rotationAngle` определяет насколько нужно повернуть элемент, чтобы он был направлен в сторону новых координат.

**Но в процессе решения столкнулся с рядом проблем:**

1. <del>Я никак не могу заставить жука поворачиваться в сторону перемещения последующей позиции.</del>
   Он поворачивается в сторону следующей позиции, но спустя некоторые время снова начинает, делать кривые повороты.
2. Движения жука не получились близко к реальным движениям, и не знаю можно ли такое сделать.
3. Если позиция оказывается слишком далеко от нынешнего положения, то жук "бежит" слишком быстро и наоборот если слишком близко то медленно

**И есть ли другой способ сделать такое? Может есть какая-то библиотека с которой можно такое реализовать, но я нашел максимально близкое только в [animate.js](https://animejs.com/documentation/#motionPath)**

Comment: @Зонтик да какая разница, та же букашка

Comment: Попроьуйте библиотеку GSAP должна подойти

Comment: @Зонтик, душнила? xD

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Я никак не могу заставить жука проворачиваться в сторону перемещения последующей позиции.

Решено. Нужно было ставить дельту Y первой, и умножать сами новые X и Y на -1, чтобы жуки не шли задом на перёд.

> 2. Движения жука не получились близко к реальным движениям, и не знаю можно ли такое сделать.

Можно что-то нахимичить с `offset-path` и с [Motion Path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Motion_Path)-ами в принципе, но мне это кажется излишним.

> 3. Если позиция оказывается слишком далеко от нынешнего положения, то жук "бежит" слишком быстро

Так происходит потому, что жуки должны прийти к одному месту в одно и то же время.

#### Решение

```js
class MoveBugs {
  static init(container) {
    const bugs = container.getElementsByClassName("bug-icon");
    const firstBug = bugs[0]
    const maxWidth = container.offsetWidth - firstBug.offsetWidth
    const maxHeight = container.offsetHeight - firstBug.offsetHeight
    const initialAngle = -45
    const moveBugs = () => this.moveBugs(bugs, maxWidth, maxHeight, initialAngle)

    moveBugs()

    setInterval(moveBugs, 2e3)
  }

  static moveBugs(bugs, maxWidth, maxHeight, initialAngle) {
    for (const bug of bugs) {
      const newX = getRandom(0, maxWidth)
      const newY = getRandom(0, maxHeight)

      const angle = this.getAngle(bug, newX, newY) - initialAngle

      bug.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg)`

      this.moveBug(bug, newX, newY)
    }
  }

  static getAngle(bug, newX, newY) {
    const currentX = bug.offsetLeft
    const currentY = bug.offsetTop
    const dx = newX - currentX
    const dy = newY - currentY

    return Math.atan2(dy * -1, dx * -1) * 180 / Math.PI
  }

  static moveBug(bug, x, y) {
    bug.style.left = x + 'px'
    bug.style.top = y + 'px'
  }
}

const container = document.getElementById('bug-container')

MoveBugs
  .init(container)

function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min
}
```

```css
#bug-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.bug-icon {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: left 5s linear, top 5s linear;
}
```

```html
<header class="header" id="bug-container">
  <img class="bug-icon" id="bug1" src="https://svgshare.com/i/t12.svg">
  <img class="bug-icon" id="bug2" src="https://svgshare.com/i/t12.svg">
  <img class="bug-icon" id="bug3" src="https://svgshare.com/i/t12.svg">
</header>
```

P.S. На лучшее решение конечно же не претендую, но надеюсь мой ответ поможет другим участникам написать более совершенное решение.

Answer (score 2):

`tx`, `ty`, `lastTargetTime` отвечают за цель к которой таракан бежит. Цель меняется случайно с интервалом около двух секунд.

`t`, `lastT` измеряют время между последовательными вызовами `update`.

`aspeed`, `vspeed` - угловая и линейная скорость таракана.

`a`, `x`, `y` - направление движения и координаты таракана.

На каждом вызове `update` таракан доворачивается на цель и бежит с постоянной скоростью. Если таракану удаётся подойти к цели достаточно близко, он двигается кругами. Это не программировалось специально, просто такая модель движения.

`window.requestAnimationFrame` - вызывает `update` для всех тараканов.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("bug-container");

const makeCockroach = icon => {
    const vspeed = 100;
    const aspeed = 2 * Math.PI;
    let lastT = 0;
    let lastTargetTime = -100;
    let a = 0;
    let x = 0;
    let y = 0;
    let tx = 0;
    let ty = 0;

    const update = t => {
        if (t >= lastTargetTime + 1.5 + Math.random()) {
            const rect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
            tx = Math.random() * rect.width ;
            ty = Math.random() * rect.height;
            lastTargetTime = t;
        }

        const dt = t - lastT;

        const ta = Math.atan2(ty - y, tx - x);
        for (; a < ta; a += 2 * Math.PI) {
        }
        for (; a > ta; a -= 2 * Math.PI) {
        }
        const a2 = a + 2 * Math.PI;
        if (ta - a < a2 - ta) {
            a = Math.min(ta, a + dt * aspeed);
        } else {
            a = Math.max(ta, a2 - dt * aspeed);
        }

        x += dt * vspeed * Math.cos(a);
        y += dt * vspeed * Math.sin(a);
        icon.style.left = x + "px";
        icon.style.top = y + "px";
        icon.style.transform = "rotate(" + (180 * a / Math.PI - 135) + "deg)";
        lastT = t;
    };

    return {'update': update};
};

const cockroaches = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.getElementsByClassName("bug-icon"),
    makeCockroach
);

const step = () => {
    const t = performance.now() / 1000;
    for (const cockroach of cockroaches) {
        cockroach.update(t);
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
};
window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```css
#bug-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}

.bug-icon {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="header" id="bug-container">
<img class="bug-icon" id="bug" src="https://svgshare.com/i/t12.svg">
<img class="bug-icon" id="bug" src="https://svgshare.com/i/t12.svg">
<img class="bug-icon" id="bug" src="https://svgshare.com/i/t12.svg">
</header>
```